# Elementor - I need to fetch the content of a revision along with its styles using a hook

Tags: css, wordpress, hook, elementor

I need to fetch the content of a revision along with its styles using a hook. I'm using the following code:

```php
echo Elementor\Plugin::instance()->frontend->get_builder_content($revision->ID);
```

However, it doesn't retrieve the CSS styles.

The `$revision->ID` is obtained using `$revisions = wp_get_post_revisions($post_id);`. For a regular post with `$post_id`, `get_builder_content` retrieves the styles successfully, but it doesn't work for revisions.